# PyInstaller: как использовать файлы, которые находятся внутри .exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

У меня имеется вот такая структура файлов:

```
Папка sounds
Папка images
settings.json
coordinates.json
lib.py (основной скрипт)
```

Для того, что бы создать *.exe* файл, я использую такую команду:

```
pyinstaller --add-data sounds;sounds --add-data images;images --add-data coordinates.json;. --add-data settings.json;. --hidden-import pynput.keyboard._win32 --hidden-import pynput.mouse._win32 --onefile lib.py
```

*(--hidden-import'ы необходимы, ибо без них не работает импорт модуля pynput)*

Однако после запуска *.exe* выдается ошибка, что файла `settings.json` не существует. Но если закинуть этот файл в папку уже с exe'шником, то все срабатывает.

Та же самая история с файлом `coordinates.json` и файлами в папках `sounds` и `images` (вместо звуков проигрывается стандартный звук ошибки *windows*, а изображения просто не находятся).

**Вопрос:** можно ли, и если да, то как читать/воиспроизводить/изменять файлы, находящиеся внутри *.exe*?
Если же изменять их нельзя, то как можно создать что-то ввиде *загрузчика*? То есть создать папку где-нибудь в `appdata` и туда загрузить эти файлы. (Имеется ввиду все это сделать должен скрипт).

Заранее благодраю, С уважением.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как оказалось, все гениально и не очень - просто.
В самой документации `PyInstaller` все описано. А именно: при запуске *exe'шника* все внутренности программы распаковываюся во временную папку windows. Соответсвенно, в скрипте нужно обращаться к ним. Вот как это нужно сделать (код из официально документации):

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    # Получаем абсолютный путь к ресурсам.
    try:
        # PyInstaller создает временную папку в _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

А далее использовать эту функцию везде, где мы указываем путь к файлам, которые должны будут лежать в *exe'шнике*. Например:

```
path_to_the_images = resourse_path('images')
```

Comment: а изменять с последующим сохранением возможно?