# Автономный исполняемый файл в PYTHON

Tags: python, exe, executable

И снова ночи! И снова нужна помощь, на этот раз не получается создать полностью автономный исполняемый файл приложения. Варант держать все файлы в одной папке не подходит, про него я читал, да и у самого получалсь таким образом запускать приложение на другом ПК.
Я нашел ветку в англоязычной части StackOverflow, но разобраться не смог. Попробую изложить то, в чем, как мне кажется, более менее разобрался.
Есть скрипт небольшой программы, все работает, все замечательно. В программе использована внешняя картинка и вот её вшить в .exe'шник не выходит. Я использовал такое руководство к действию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Находится она в этой ветке: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/63997336#63997336

Из того, что я там понял это:
1 - в скрип, встрайвается сл. код:

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

2 - нужно задействовать def resource_path в скрипте, связав с картинками:

```
img_dir = resource_path("img")
```

Уже на этом этапе я не понимаю как это сделать. В моем скрипте (прикреплю полный листинг в конце), для иконки окна используется сл. конструкция:

```
icon = tk.PhotoImage(file=r'H:\PYTHON\CATRi\res\CATRi.png')
app.iconphoto(False, icon)
```

Каким образом связать это с тем что я написал выше, что бы задействовать def resource_path, не понимаю.

3 - создать и отредактировать файл .spec, тут вроде бы все понятно.

4 - скомпилировать и радоваться. С этим тоже вопросов не возникает.

Прикладываю полный листинг программы:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sys
import os

def res_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- MAIN WINDOW
app = tk.Tk()
app.title('CATRi')
icon = tk.PhotoImage(file=r'H:\PYTHON\CATRi\res\CATRi.png')
app.iconphoto(False, icon)
app.geometry('300x600')
app.resizable(width=False, height=False)

app.update_idletasks()
s = app.geometry()
s = s.split('+')
s = s[0].split('x')
width_app = int(s[0])
height_app = int(s[1])
w = app.winfo_screenwidth()
h = app.winfo_screenheight()
w = w // 2
h = h // 2
w = w - width_app // 2
h = h - height_app // 2
app.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(w, h))

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- INTERFACE
# ---------------------------------------------------------------- Patient Section
labelTitle = tk.Label(text='Пациент:', fg='#eee', bg='#333')
labelTitle.place(relwidth=1.0, relx=.5, rely=.02, anchor='center')

patientName = tk.StringVar()
patientNameLabel = tk.Label(text='ФИО:')
patientNameLabel.place(x=8, y=45, anchor='w')
patientName_entry = tk.Entry(textvariable=patientName)
patientName_entry.place(x=45, y=45, relwidth=.8, anchor='w')

patientDate = tk.StringVar()
patientDateLabel = tk.Label(text='Дата рождения:')
patientDateLabel.place(x=8, y=68, anchor='w')
patientDate_entry = tk.Entry(textvariable=patientDate)
patientDate_entry.place(x=101, y=68, relwidth=.612, anchor='w')

patientSexLabel = tk.Label(text='Пол:')
patientSexLabel.place(x=68, y=92, anchor='w')
patientSelectSex = ttk.Combobox(app, values=['мужской',
                                             'женский'])
patientSelectSex.place(x=101, y=92, relwidth=.25, anchor='w')

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- PARAMETERS
labelTitle = tk.Label(text='Анамнез:', fg='#eee', bg='#333')
labelTitle.place(relwidth=1.0, relx=.5, rely=.206, anchor='center')

# ---------------------------------------------------------------- Course Select
courseLabel = tk.Label(text='1. Течение:')
courseLabel.place(x=7, y=150, anchor='w')
courseSelect = ttk.Combobox(app, values=['бессимптомное',
                                         'симптомное',
                                         ''])
courseSelect.place(x=11, y=177, relwidth=.40, anchor='w')
courseSelect.current(2)

# ---------------------------------------------------------------- Stenosis Select
stenosisLabel = tk.Label(text='2. Стеноз ВСА:')
stenosisLabel.place(x=162, y=150, anchor='w')
stenosisSelect = ttk.Combobox(app, values=['нет',
                                           'менее 50%',
                                           'от 50 до 70%',
                                           'более 70%',
                                           'окклюзия',
                                           ''])
stenosisSelect.place(x=165, y=177, relwidth=.40, anchor='w')
stenosisSelect.current(5)

# ---------------------------------------------------------------- Plaque Select
plaqueLabel = tk.Label(text='3. Бляшка:')
plaqueLabel.place(x=8, y=227, anchor='w')
plaqueSelect = ttk.Combobox(app, values=['нет',
                                         'стабильная',
                                         'нестабильная',
                                         ''])
plaqueSelect.place(x=11, y=254, relwidth=.40, anchor='w')
plaqueSelect.current(3)

# ---------------------------------------------------------------- Hearth Select
hearthLabel = tk.Label(text='4. Очаг ишемии:')
hearthLabel.place(x=162, y=227, anchor='w')
hearthSelect = ttk.Combobox(app, values=['нет',
                                         'менее 2,5 см',
                                         '2,5 см',
                                         'более 2,5 см',
                                         ''])
hearthSelect.place(x=165, y=254, relwidth=.40, anchor='w')
hearthSelect.current(4)

# ---------------------------------------------------------------- Transformation Select
transformationLabel = '5. Геморрагическая \n трансформация:'
transformationLabel = tk.Label(text=transformationLabel, justify=tk.LEFT)
transformationLabel.place(x=7, y=300, anchor='w')
transformationSelect = ttk.Combobox(app, values=['нет',
                                                 'есть',
                                                 ''])
transformationSelect.place(x=11, y=331, relwidth=.40, anchor='w')
transformationSelect.current(2)

# ---------------------------------------------------------------- Deficit Select
deficitLabel = '6. Неврологический \n дефицит:'
deficitLabel = tk.Label(text=deficitLabel, justify=tk.LEFT)
deficitLabel.place(x=162, y=300, anchor='w')
deficitSelect = ttk.Combobox(app, values=['нет',
                                          'Ренкин 1-3',
                                          'Ренкин 4-5',
                                          ''])
deficitSelect.place(x=165, y=331, relwidth=.40, anchor='w')
deficitSelect.current(3)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- CONCLUSION
labelTitle = tk.Label(text='Заключение:', fg='#eee', bg='#333')
labelTitle.place(relwidth=1.0, relx=.5, rely=.68, anchor='center')


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ENGINE
def clearPatientValues():
    patientName_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    patientDate_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    patientSelectSex.set('')


def appAnalyse():
    courseVar = courseSelect.get()
    stenosisVar = stenosisSelect.get()
    plaqueVar = plaqueSelect.get()
    hearthVar = hearthSelect.get()
    transformationVar = transformationSelect.get()
    deficitVar = deficitSelect.get()

    if courseVar == 'бессимптомное':
        courseVar = int('0')
    elif courseVar == 'симптомное':
        courseVar = int('2')
    elif courseVar == '':
        courseVar = str('')

    if stenosisVar == 'нет':
        stenosisVar = int('0')
    elif stenosisVar == 'менее 50%':
        stenosisVar = int("1")
    elif stenosisVar == 'от 50 до 70%':
        stenosisVar = int('5')
    elif stenosisVar == 'более 70%':
        stenosisVar = int('10')
    elif stenosisVar == 'окклюзия':
        stenosisVar = int('30')
    elif stenosisVar == '':
        stenosisVar = str('')

    if plaqueVar == 'нет':
        plaqueVar = int('0')
    elif plaqueVar == 'стабильная':
        plaqueVar = int('1')
    elif plaqueVar == 'нестабильная':
        plaqueVar = int('5')
    elif plaqueVar == '':
        plaqueVar = str('')

    if hearthVar == 'нет':
        hearthVar = int('0')
    elif hearthVar == 'менее 2,5 см':
        hearthVar = int('1')
    elif hearthVar == '2,5 см':
        hearthVar = int('2')
    elif hearthVar == 'более 2,5 см':
        hearthVar = int('50')
    elif hearthVar == '':
        hearthVar = str('')

    if transformationVar == 'нет':
        transformationVar = int('0')
    elif transformationVar == 'есть':
        transformationVar = int('50')
    elif transformationVar == '':
        transformationVar = str('')

    if deficitVar == 'нет':
        deficitVar = int('0')
    elif deficitVar == 'Ренкин 1-3':
        deficitVar = int('5')
    elif deficitVar == 'Ренкин 4-5':
        deficitVar = int('50')
    elif deficitVar == '':
        deficitVar = str('')

    print(courseVar, stenosisVar, plaqueVar, hearthVar, transformationVar, deficitVar)

    SCORE = courseVar + stenosisVar + plaqueVar + hearthVar + transformationVar + deficitVar
    print(SCORE)

    if SCORE == '':
        conclusion.config(text=f'Выберите значения!')
    elif SCORE == 0:
        conclusion.config(
            text=f'ЗАКЛЮЧЕНИЕ:\nРиск ОНМК отсутствует.\n\nРЕКОМЕНДОВАНО:\nСпециальных назначений не требуется.\n')
    elif 0 < SCORE <= 4:
        conclusion.config(
            text=f'ЗАКЛЮЧЕНИЕ:\nРиск ОНМК минимальный.\nОперативное лечение не показано.\n\nРЕКОМЕНДОВАНО:\nУЗАС сонных артерий + консультация\nсосудистого хирурга 1 раз в год.\n')
    elif 4 < SCORE < 6:
        conclusion.config(
            text=f'ЗАКЛЮЧЕНИЕ:\nРиск ОНМК минимальный.\nОперативное лечение не показано.\n\nРЕКОМЕНДОВАНО:\nУЗАС сонных артерий + консультация\nсосудистого хирурга 2 раз в год.\n')
    elif 6 <= SCORE < 12:
        conclusion.config(
            text=f'ЗАКЛЮЧЕНИЕ:\nРиск ОНМК незначительный.\nОперативное лечение не показано.\n\nРЕКОМЕНДОВАНО:\nУЗАС сонных артерий + консультация\nсосудистого хирурга 2 раз в год.\n')
    elif 12 <= SCORE < 25:
        conclusion.config(
            text=f'ЗАКЛЮЧЕНИЕ:\nРиск ОНМК высокий.\nПоказано оперативное лечение.\n\nРЕКОМЕНДОВАНО:\nКонсультация сосудистого хирурга\nдля решения вопроса\nо плановом оперативном лечении.')
    elif SCORE >= 50:
        conclusion.config(
            text=f'ЗАКЛЮЧЕНИЕ:\nОперативное лечение не показано.\n\nРЕКОМЕНДОВАНО:\nКонсультация сосудистого хирурга через 1 мес.\n')
    elif 25 < SCORE < 50:
        conclusion.config(
            text=f'ЗАКЛЮЧЕНИЕ:\nОперативное лечение не показано.\n\nРЕКОМЕНДОВАНО:\nУЗАС сонных артерий + консультация\nсосудистого хирурга 2 раза в год.\n')


conclusion = ''
conclusion = tk.Label(text=conclusion, anchor='center', height=10, width=41)
conclusion.place(relx=.012, rely=.835, anchor='w')


# ---------------------------------------------------------------- Clearing
def clearComboboxValues():
    courseSelect.set('')
    stenosisSelect.set('')
    plaqueSelect.set('')
    hearthSelect.set('')
    transformationSelect.set('')
    deficitSelect.set('')
    conclusion.config(text=f'')


# ---------------------------------------------------------------- Buttons
message_button = tk.Button(text='X', command=clearPatientValues)
message_button.place(x=261, y=92, relheight=.035, relwidth=.08, anchor="w")

message_button = tk.Button(text='Анализ', command=appAnalyse)
message_button.place(x=165, y=370, relwidth=.40, anchor='w')

message_button = tk.Button(text='Сброс', command=clearComboboxValues)
message_button.place(x=11, y=370, relwidth=.40, anchor='w')

app.mainloop()
```

Структура папок с программой:

```
H:/PYTHON/CATRi
          CATRi.py
          res/ # directory containing the image files
          main.spec
```

Изображение иконки (если потребуется):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сбственно если кто-то может, подскажите как можно реализовать автономность, по средством алгоритма, который я привел выше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Снова ночи! Получилось решить проблему с автономностью исполняемого файла, поэтому напишу здесь свой алгоритм, может в дальнейшем кому-то пригодится. Разобраться помог ответ Woopertail'а из этой [ветки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1252651/514045), за что ему огромное человеческое спасибо.
Начнем с описания структуры папок с программой:

```
E:/PYTHON/ARSiS/
          ARSiS.py
          res/ # тут лежат файлы изображений (_lightning.png, _logo.png, _clear.png, _border.png, ARSiS.ico)
```

**1. Внесение изменений в скрипт программы:**

Первым делом в шапку скрипта, нужно пометить следующий код:

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    # Получаем абсолютный путь к ресурсам.
    try:
        # PyInstaller создает временную папку в _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

Суть функции выше в следующем:

> *...при запуске exe'шника все внутренности программы распаковываюся во временную папку Windows. Соответственно, в скрипте нужно обращаться к ним.* [Woopertail]

Для обращения к этим файлам и нужна вышеприведенная функция. При добавлении в скрипт программы выглядеть это будет следующим образом:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import sys
import os

def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

# начало скрпита самой программы
app = tk.Tk()
app.title('ARSiS')
```

Помимо самой функции обязательно нужно добавить две строки:

```
import sys
import os
```

После того как функция добавлена ее нужно будет вызывать в тех местах, где указываются используемые внешние файлы. Для примера буду использовать часть кода с параметрами окна программы, до и после интеграции в нее вышеприведенной функции. Пример кода, до модификации:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time
 
app = tk.Tk()
app.title('ARSiS assistant')
icon = tk.PhotoImage(file = r'E:\PYTHON\ARSiS\res\_lightning.png')
app.iconphoto(False, icon)
app.geometry('400x800')

app.update_idletasks()
s = app.geometry()
s = s.split('+')
s = s[0].split('x')
width_app = int(s[0])
height_app = int(s[1])
 
w = app.winfo_screenwidth()
h = app.winfo_screenheight()
w = w // 2
h = h // 2 
w = w - width_app // 2
h = h - height_app // 2
app.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(w, h))

app.resizable(width = False, height = False)
app['background'] = '#B2DFDB'
```

Как видно, в скрипте выше используется файл _lightning.png в качестве иконки окна программы. Модифицируем скрипт и получим следующее:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import sys
import os

def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

app = tk.Tk()
app.title('ARSiS')
icon = tk.PhotoImage(file = resource_path('res\_lightning.png'))
app.iconphoto(False, icon)
app.geometry('400x800')

app.update_idletasks()
s = app.geometry()
s = s.split('+')
s = s[0].split('x')
width_app = int(s[0])
height_app = int(s[1])
 
w = app.winfo_screenwidth()
h = app.winfo_screenheight()
w = w // 2
h = h // 2 
w = w - width_app // 2
h = h - height_app // 2
app.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(w, h))

app.resizable(width = False, height = False)
app['background'] = '#B2DFDB'
```

Было:

```
icon = tk.PhotoImage(file = r'E:\PYTHON\ARSiS\res\_lightning.png')
```

Стало:

```
icon = tk.PhotoImage(file = resource_path('res\_lightning.png'))
```

Аналогичным образом нужно обратиться к функции везде, где происходит обращение к внешним файлам. В моем случае, это были еще три изображения:

```
ARSiS_Logo = tk.PhotoImage(file = resource_path('res\_logo.png'))
ClearIcon = tk.PhotoImage(file = resource_path('res\_clear.png'))
separator01 = tk.PhotoImage(file = resource_path('res\_border.png'))
```

После того, как все изменения внесены, проверяем работу программы (все должно работать) и приступаем к компиляции.

**2. Запаковка:**

На одном из форумов я вычитал, что в случае скриптовых языков слово компиляция не совсем корректно, точнее будет запаковка. И для нее я использовал Auto-py-to-exe, со следующим набором параметров:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То же самое, но в консольном представлении:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --icon "E:/PYTHON/ARSiS/res/ARSiS.ico" --add-data "E:/PYTHON/ARSiS/res;res/" --add-data "E:/PYTHON/ARSiS/res/_border.png;." --add-data "E:/PYTHON/ARSiS/res/_clear.png;." --add-data "E:/PYTHON/ARSiS/res/_lightning.png;." --add-data "E:/PYTHON/ARSiS/res/_logo.png;." --add-data "E:/PYTHON/ARSiS/res/ARSiS.ico;."  "E:/PYTHON/ARSiS/ARSiS.py"
```

После этого в папке output, появился полностью автономный исполняемый файл. Для проверки, директория с папкой res была переименована. Но, программа запустилась без ошибок.

Во многих решениях фигурировал этап редактирования файла .spec, но мне он не понадобился, все прекрасно запустилось. Даже на другом компьютере (файл был отправлен по Telegram другому человеку).

Спасибо за внимание! Возможно, кому нибудь это сэкономит кучу времени! ;)